# jQuery pass variable from 1 function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, html-table

I'm doing a 3 step jQuery exercise when the final step requires getting information from the previous function. The first 2 steps work. However, I can't get the 3rd function to run.

**1st step = Users select a category from the drop down menu**
JavaScript:

```
var selectedCategory;
var textNameOfBusinessCategorySelected;
var nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory;
function businessListingResults(databaseList) {
  selectedCategory = $("#select-business-listing option:selected").val();
  textNameOfBusinessCategorySelected = $("#select-business-listing option:selected").text();
  nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory = databaseList[selectedCategory];
  for (findBusinessNamesUnderCategory in nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory) {
       $("#listingResults").append("<li>" + findBusinessNamesUnderCategory + "</li>");
       console.log(findBusinessNamesUnderCategory);
  } // line ends for in loop
} // line closes function
```

HTML:

```
<h4 class="title">Select a Category from the drop down menu to check your local businesses</h4>
  <select id="select-business-listing" name="submitted[select_your_program]" class="select-a-business">
    <option value="musEnt">Music and Entertainment</option>
    <option value="paint">Paint</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <button class="listingsBtn" onclick="businessListingResults(businessListings)">Search Listings</button>
</div>
<p id="listingResults"></p>
```

**2nd step = Businesses under category appear in ul list and user select a business**
JavaSript:

```
function clickListingLink() {
  // function is for when a link is clicked after list of businesses appear
  $('#listOfBusinesses').on('click','li', function(){     
    console.log('you clicked me'); 
    seeListingInfoTable(); 
    $("hr").show();    
  });
}
```

**3rd step = Once user select a business from ul list, a table appears with that business info. This is the part I can't get to work. Below is the table for the business but it doesn't appear once the business is clicked.**
JavaScript:

```
function seeListingInfoTable() {
  var tbl = "";
    tbl += '<table class="table table-hover">';
    tbl += '</table>';
      tbl += '<tbody>';
      tbl += '<caption class="listingTitle">' + titleOfBusinessSelected + '</caption>';
      tbl += '<tr>';
      tbl += '<th>Address</th>';
      tbl += '<th>Phone Number</th>';
      tbl += '<th>Website</th>';
      tbl += '<th>Specialty</th>';
      tbl += '</tr>';
      tbl += '<tr>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Address"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Phone Number"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Website"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '<td><div class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="fname">' + businessLinkSelected["Specialty"] + '</div></td>';
      tbl += '</tr>';
    tbl += '</tbody>';
    tbl += '</table>';
    $(document).find("#infoTable").html(tbl);
} // line ends seeListingInfoTable function
```

I'm not sure how to connect the variables to the table function so the information can appear in the table for whatever option the user selected.

Comment: It should be `$('#listingResults').on('click','li', function(){` in your second js code block, since that's the id you gave to your element. I don't see any `listOfBusinesses`. That's why your click event never triggers. Besides, your `listingResults` element should be an `ul` or `ol` and not a `p` tag if you wish to populate it with `li` elements

Comment: @TheWanderingMind  #listOBusinesses is the name of the ul list. I didn't make my p tag a ul or li because I already made the list a ul right before the for loop runs. I appended a ul before the list prints out.

Comment: In the code you provided, I don't see you appending a ul with the id `listOfBusinesses` before the list prints out. Is there some code lacking?

Comment: @TheWanderingMind Here's the updated code: $("#listingResults").append("Business Listings Under Category <strong>" + textNameOfBusinessCategorySelected + "</strong> are: <br/><br/><ul id='listOfBusinesses'>");
      for (findBusinessNamesUnderCategory in nameOfBusinessesUnderCategory) {
           $("#listingResults").append("<li><a href='javascript-exercise-16.html#bottomOfPage' onclick='clickListingLink'>"+ findBusinessNamesUnderCategory + "</a></li>");
      } 
      $("#listingResults").append("</ul>");

Comment: So you set the onclick event to each of your li elements to `clickListingLink`. But that function is attaching a click event to each of your li elements. See where I'm going with this? Remove your `$('#listOfBusinesses').on('click','li', function(){ ` block in your `clickListingLink` function.

Comment: I have the click event for each li element that way when the user selects any of them/ clicks on them an event will happen. The event that's suppose to take place is the table function with all the info about the business populated in the table.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused as to what your code really is. If you'd create a fiddle I could help you more easily

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks

Comment: @TheWanderingMind Hi I just created a fiddle. Here's the link. Hopefully this helps it make more sense @ https://jsfiddle.net/Angel91/8yzr7men/1/